# Change the label on Value picker with PickListSearch

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

Is there anyway to change the text label on value picker when the PickListSearch ? This is xpage Domino 10. It seems to be dojoattachpoint inputText. Thanks Bob
[image: Example highlight in yellow]

Comment: Been able to hide the area with css but really like to know to change text.

Answer (score 0):

How about making computing the label value to be a scope variable? Your code can change the scope variable and partial update of the label or container.

Comment: That would be great if I knew what to set on the control.  Haven't been able to identified the property to that relate to that label.